# nuxtJS how to make javascript load dynamically by page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to insert this script to nuxtJS project and I want it to load dynamically by page.

```js
<!-- LINE Tag Base Code -->
<!-- Do Not Modify -->
<script>
(function(g,d,o){
  g._ltq=g._ltq||[];g._lt=g._lt||function(){g._ltq.push(arguments)};
  var h=location.protocol==='https:'?'https://d.line-scdn.net':'http://d.line-cdn.net';
  var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=1;
  s.src=o||h+'/n/line_tag/public/release/v1/lt.js';
  var t=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);
    })(window, document);
_lt('init', {
  customerType: 'account',
  tagId: 'xxxxx'
});
_lt('send', 'pv', ['xxxxx']);
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
       src="https://tr.line.me/tag.gif?c_t=lap&t_id=xxxxx&e=pv&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
<!-- End LINE Tag Base Code -->
```

The important thing is `tagId: 'xxxxx'` this should be change dynamically by page. for example,

```
wwww.sample.com/shop1 will load tagId: 'shop_tag1'
wwww.sample.com/shop2 will load tagId: 'shop_tag2'
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of tracker is this ? If it does not have any way of setting it app-wise, I guess that you need to have a middleware that is running your function and grabbing the dynamic part from each page.

This can be helpful: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware/
Also, I did found some issues on using a middleware in a `layout`, but maybe it's just me, if it does work on your side, you could just dump your `js` there too.